# The Chrome Root Store is not reading self-signed certs injected into the Windows trusted root store

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, ca

We're running our own certificate authority. Based on https://smallstep.com/docs/step-ca. And CRL is enabled on this CA.

I've ensured that the public certificates of the root and the intermediary is injected into the local Windows clients trusted root store.

The issue is that if we don't disable ChromeRootStoreEnabled in the Windows registry, leaf certificates are marked as invalid by Chrome ( NET::ERR_CERT_UNABLE_TO_CHECK_REVOCATION is thrown by Google Chrome ).

If we disable ChromeRootStoreEnabled in the Windows Registry ( by setting it 1 as described here > https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ChromeRootStoreEnabled ) there's no problem.

So I did some troubleshooting with the `chrome://net-export` tool to create a net-log when accessing a website protected by a leaf certificate issued by the CA.

This is the net-export log > https://gist.github.com/LarsBingBong/7205e4cac9da91b4adcae9fd6d26d034

So it looks like Chrome is not liking or actually being able to read the public certificates of the root and the intermediary that are injected into the Windows Trusted Root Store, when the Chrome Root Store is enabled.
How can I pinpoint why Google Chrome is NOT reading these certificates from the Windows Trusted Root Store?

According to the below:

```
The Chrome Certificate Verifier considers locally-managed certificates during the certificate verification process. This means if an enterprise distributes a root CA certificate as trusted to its users (for example, by a Windows Group Policy Object), it will be considered trusted in Chrome.
```

The above from > https://blog.chromium.org/2022/09/announcing-launch-of-chrome-root-program.html

So Google Chrome should read certificates injected into the Windows Trusted Root store. I've tried injecting the pub. certs into the machine and the personal store in the Windows trusted root store.

So any help on how I can troubleshoot why Google Chrome is either:

- not reading the pub. certs from the Windows Trusted Root Store or
- not liking the data of the certificates

The thinking being that either or above is the culprit.

---

We're running:

- Google Chrome v111
- Windows 10 & 11
- The certificate data can be found in the attach net-export log. If you feel like analyzing these certs with e.g. crt.sh

---

Thank you and I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

---

> N.B. I did try posting this in the Google community. However, I keep getting *You've reached the limit for posting. Please try again later.*. Tried from two different Google accounts. Further, by posting it here on stackoverflow I hope to get to a broader audience.